# sobre escribir en el _id predeterminado de mongo

Tags: mongodb

Tengo esta `collection` en mongo, pero mi pregunta es hay alguna manera que al hacer una `collection` con `insert` no me de el `_id` predeterminado ya que en esta ocasión ocupo que mi `id` sea la segunda linea.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ca1abb6ce037511f000628e"),
        "id" : "sjohnson",
        "name" : "Steve Johnson"
}
```

Necesito que sea de esta manera :

```
   {
            "id" : "sjohnson",
            "name" : "Steve Johnson"
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo a la [documentación oficial](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/) si tu colección no tiene una columna `_id` de manera explícita; entonces MongoDB creará una columna `_id` e escribirá un valor **hexadecimal** del tipo `ObjectId`.

Si tu vas a manejar con valores propios la columna de `_id` entonces solo deberás asegurarte que dicha columna reciba valores únicos *que sean provistos por ti misma*

**EJEMPLO 1**

Creamos una base de datos de ejemplo así

```
use mydb
```

Posterior, ejecutamos el siguiente comando para insertar un valor en una colección users

```
db.users.insert({ "_id": 1, "name": "alfa" })
```

Si ejecutamos un `find()` a dicha colección nos devolverá esto

```
db.users.find()
```

Resultado

> {"_id": 1, "name": "alfa"}

Con lo anterior has podido comprobar que si tu declaras de manera explícita una columna `_id` esa se respetará y mongoDB no agregará una por defecto

**EJEMPLO 2**

Ahora vamos a insertar un nuevo registro, pero esta vez omitiremos la columna `_id` lo cual le dará paso al gestor de mongoDB de agregar la columna por el mismo asignándole un valor por defecto

```
db.users.insert({ "name": "beta", "age": 28 })
```

Si ejecuto ahora el siguiente comando

```
db.users.find()
```

Obtendré lo siguiente como resultado

> { "_id": ObjectId("5ca1b6a90193271048449020"), "name": "beta", "age": 28 }

Answer (score 1):

El campo`_id` de MongoDB, debe estar presente en cada documento que sea almacenado en la base de datos. Si un documento no posee dicho campo al momento de realizar un `insert`, MongoDB creará dicho campo por nosotros.

Por lo tanto no podemos deshacernos de dicho campo. Es decir no lo puedes ***quitar*** de tus documentos

En tu pregunta, planteas que quieres usar tu propio campo `id`. Tienes 2 opciones:

1. Puedes sobreescribir el campo `_id`, enviando en tu documento el valor para dicho campo. Sin embargo, debes poder garantizar que dicho campo sea único. Tal vez, `sjohnson` no sea lo más adecuado. Si un usuario se llama `Steve Johnson` y generas el `_id` tomando la inicial del nombre y el apellido, entonces, `Sam Johnson` por ejemplo ya es un nombre que no podrás almacenar con este procedimiento. En muchos lugares se usa el número de documento de identidad como campo `_id` ya que se supone una relación única. En otros casos se usa el correo electrónico. También se usa un valor tipo `integer` de autoincremento. Por allí ya tienes de donde tirar. Solo recuerda que al momento de insertar tu documento, éste debe tener un campo `_id` con un valor que sea único para dicho documento.
2. Puedes ignorar el hecho de que existe dicho campo, y omitirlo al momento de realizar tu consulta. Además puedes crear tu propio campo `id`, tal como lo haces actualmente y usar el mismo valor tanto para `id` como para `_id`, siempre teniendo en cuenta lo que comento en el punto anterior.

Un ejemplo podría ser el siguiente:

```
> db.users.insert({"_id": "Y12345678W", "id": "Y12345678W", "name": "Steve", "lastname": "Johnson"})
```

Al momento de realizar la consulta puedo decirle a Mongo que omita traerme el campo `_id` por ejemplo con la siguiente consulta `find`:

```
> db.users.find({}, {"_id": 0})
{"id": "Y12345678W", "name": "Steve", "lastname": "Johnson"}
```

Como puedes ver, en la consulta he pasado como segundo argumento un documento llamado [parámetro `projection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#find-projection), el cual especifica los campos que deseo que me devuelva la consulta. Un valor de `0` (`false`) indica que dicho campo no será devuelto, y un valor de `1` (`true`) indica que si será devuelto.

Cuando se omite el parámetro `projection`, MongoDB devuelve todos los campos del documento. En cambio si se pasa un parámetro `projection` indicando un (o algunos) valor en `false`, el resto se asume `true`, excepto por el campo `_id` que siempre se asume `true`. Eso es lo que sucede en la consulta que acabamos de realizar.

Por otro lado, si pasamos un parámetro `projection`, indicando un (o algunos) valor en `true`, el resto se asume como `false` (excepto el campo `_id`) y no son devueltos por la consulta.

Por ejemplo si deseamos solo el campo `id` y el campo `lastname` podemos realizar la siguiente consulta:

```
>db.users.find({}, {"_id": 0, "id": 1, "lastname": 1})
{"id": "Y12345678W", "lastname": "Johnson"}
```

Por último, cabe destacar que el único campo que MongoDB utiliza como `PK` es el campo `_id`, esto significa que no se puede establecer otro campo como `Primary Key`.

Además, MongoDB permite establecer cualquier otro campo como [`unique index`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-properties/), (entiéndase que no `Primary Key`) que debe cumplir las condiciones necesarias para ser considerado índice tipo único.

Espero que esto aclare tu duda.